# Приложение и служба в одном EXE на C#

Tags: c#, service

Стоит задача написать службу которая должна показывать одну единственную форму ввода, но беда в том что службы в Windows не могут иметь форм, ни своих, ни какие либо образом подключаемых.

В связи с этим вопрос - как в тот же EXE впихнуть и приложение ?
Например на Delphi можно в один exe создать и приложение и службу. И они прекрасно будут работать.
Можно ли сделать подобное в приложение на C#.

Comment: - Расскажите, пожалуйста, как вы себе представляете службу (`service`), которая показывает форму ввода.

- Любое приложение в `Windows` можно использовать как службу. Самый простой способ это сделать — добавить в уже существующее приложение поддержку параметра командной типа `/RunAsService`, который и будет запускать приложение в режиме службы. Дальше вопрос стоит только в регистрации этой службы в операционной системе.

Comment: Мне будет достаточно что бы служба дергала свой же exe запуская его как приложение. Это даст возможность показывать формы, что мне и нужно.  
То есть Вы хотите сказать, что достаточно создать в приложение наследников классов **Installer** и **ServiceBase* определяющих службу и этого будет достаточно?..  
Логично, но нужно попробовать...

Comment: @t1nk: С правами какого пользователя бежит служба, и какого — приложение? Что, если залогинились несколько пользователей?

---
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/22/712677.aspx

Comment: @VladD Естественно что служба предполагает системную учетную запись. А приложение должно запускаться у активного узера (предполагается Windows XP / 7).

Comment: @t1nk: почитайте всё же мою ссылку и поймите, что понятие "активного юзера" лишено смысла.

> A common question I see is, "From a service, how do I do X with the currently logged-on user?" (Where "X" can be a variety of things such as interact with them or impersonate them.) But who says that there's only one?

Comment: @VladD Да мне пофиг имеет оно смысл это понятие или нет, мне нужно в один exe-запихнуть и службу и приложение!  
Как потом будет организовываться их взаимодействие - к вопросу не относится.  
Меня интересует сейчас сама возможность засунуть в EXE с сервисом приложение или наоборот.  
Можете что по теме ответить, без полемики не по теме?

Comment: @t1nk: Все, кто мог и хотел ответить, ответили. Если вас не интересуют комментарии к вашему вопросу, возможно, вам вместо вопросов на нашем сайте надо нанять фрилансера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то это именно то, что вам нужно:

[Как разместить службу WCF в управляемом приложении](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms731758.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Вы, наверно, if (Environment.UserInteractive) имели в виду?
http://usanov.net/2149-c-zapusk-windows-servisov-kak-konsolnyx-prilozhenij